# How to make Spark not to lose last row of CSV file if load from Dataset[String]?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

We have the following CSV file:

```
RWA
Country of exposure
Credit risk asset class
Projection period
Scenario
RWA
```

RWA in first line is header. The last line is equal to the header, but it is not a header.
When the CSV file contents is loaded from Dataset[String] like

```
import spark.implicits._
val source: Array[String] = (
      "RWA\n" +
      "Country of exposure\n" +
      "Credit risk asset class\n" +
      "Projection period\n" +
      "Scenario\n" +
      "RWA"
      ).split("\n")
val csvData: Dataset[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(source).toDS()
val df = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", value = true).csv(csvData)
// df.count() == 4 unexpectedly
```

Expected df.count() is 5 but it is actually 4.

If the same CSV is loaded from file then this problem doesn't happen:

```
val tempFile = Files.createTempFile("tmp", ".csv")
val res = "RWA\n" +
      "Country of exposure\n" +
      "Credit risk asset class\n" +
      "Projection period\n" +
      "Scenario\n" +
      "RWA"
Files.writeString(tempFile, res)
val df = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", value = true)
  .csv(tempFile.toString)
// df.count() == 5 as expected
```

**Is there a way to tell to Spark act the same when load from Dataset?**

Scala version: 2.12.14

Spark version: 3.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is this function that filters the last row: `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils#filterHeaderLine`

If you set the `header` option to `true`, this function will remove all rows equal to the first line which is the header.

You may wonder why?! Use this script to save a dataframe, and investigate the files:
`df.repartition(2).write.option("header", true).csv("output.csv")`

Now, try to read the `output.csv` file. The reason behind this behavior is that when Spark wants to read a csv file, there may be multiple files, so there may be multiple header rows!

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say "Thank you!" 
You're absolutely right. I decided to load data from file path (or URL) to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really funny behaviors, that I can't explain

Now, I don't know your real usecase, but if you have an Array[String] to convert to RDD using the first line as header, I think you should not do it this way (converting to a RDD[String] and using spark.read.csv(...) on it)

Somethink like that should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

val header = source(0).split(",")
val schema = StructType(header.map(f => StructField(f, StringType, nullable = false))))
val data = source.tail.map(line => Row(line.split(","):_*)).toSeq

spark.createDataset(data)(RowEncoder(schema)).show
```

Comment: Better later then never. Thank you for the answer and sorry for late reply.
I decided to load data from file path or URL to eliminate this issue.